# запуск jar с вложенными библиотеками jar из командной строки cmd на as400

Tags: jar

Пытаюсь пустить файл "banku3462.jar" (далее по тексту jar файл) в операционной системе AS400.
Из IDE работает.

Команду прописал так:

```
QSH CMD('cd /gcp; java -jar /gcp/banku3462.jar
ru.webengine.server.reports.u3462.U3462ExportForDate                            
-M=B -D1=2022-02-01 -D2=2022-02-01 -C=A -K=Y -P=/GCP/EX/')
```

где
CMD - начинаем работу с командной строкой.
cd /gcp; - директория по умолчанию для чтения файлов настроек с сервера.
U3462ExportForDate это класс, в котором содерижится main. След. строка это параметры запуска, которые передаём в main.

Ошибка:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (ru.rb.cfg.SystemConfiguration).                     
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.                                                
com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2SQLTimeoutException: Processing of the SQL statement ended.  Reason code 61682.
 at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2SQLException.createException(DB2SQLException.java:136)                     
 at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2ConnectionRuntimeImpl.SQLConnect(Native Method)                            
 at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2ConnectionRuntimeImpl.connect(DB2ConnectionRuntimeImpl.java:176)           
 at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Connection.<init>(DB2Connection.java:644)                                  
 at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.handleURLProcessing(DB2Driver.java:1753)                            
 at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:1285)                                        
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:675)                                       
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:258)                                       
 at lv.gcpartners.bank.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:82)                      
 at ru.webengine.server.reports.u3462.U3462ExportForDate.main(U3462ExportForDate.java:381)
```

Из IDE программа работает. В корне в каталоге lib лежат сторонние библиотеки:

```
log4j-core-2.18.0.jar log4j-api-2.18.0.jar commons-io-2.11.0.jar poi-5.2.2.jar JT400.jar production5.jar ojdbc6-11.1.0.6.0.jar cfg-core-1.0.16.jar 
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar log4j-1.2.12.jar
```

Они же и попадают в сборку jar.
p.s. программа старая, поэтому MAVEN нет и перенести проект на MAVEN очень трудоемко.

Comment: У Вас ошибка ругается на невозможность подключения к БД по таймауту `DB2SQLTimeoutException`, а не отсутствие каких-либо классов. Приложение скорее всего не видит базу данных. По поводу warning с логированием, где находится файл конфигурации `log4j` и видит ли его приложение?

Comment: Да, ошибка в строчке: connection = ConnectionFactory.getFactory().getConnection( driver, host, user, pswd);   Думаю да, ошибка связана с тем, что приложение не видит библиотеки, которые находятся внутри jar. Как это исправить - в этом и вопрос мой. Может команду CMD нужно поправить?

Comment: Библиотека как раз пытается подключится к базе данных, она уже есть в приложении. Проверьте `host` который указали, что по нему есть нужная БД. `log4j:WARN` в вопросе указывает на отсутствие конфигурации логера и скорее всего запускается с дефолтными настройками.

Comment: помогло, но теперь другая ошибка, как будто я входные параметры не передаю. Но ведь передаю в последней строчке в командной строке. Ошибка: 
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 52                                    
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2744)                                                         
ru.webengine.server.reports.u3462.U3462ExportForDate.parseInputParametrs(U3462ExportForDate.java:315)
 at ru.webengine.server.reports.u3462.U3462ExportForDate.main(U3462ExportForDate.java:387)

Comment: Дополните вопрос, как передаются данные, через какой параметр. И как потом обрабатываются эти данные. Судя по ошибке, передается пустая строка.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо приходит пустая строка, т.к. на вход функции приходит String args[]. Затем этот массив (далее по тексту "as") при попытке обратиться к первому элементу выдаёт ошибку "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1". В строчке `String str = as[j];`

[image: так передаю параметры в IDE, там работает. Только директория другая]

Через IDE как на картинке работает передача параметров.

Comment: Могу порекомендовать вывести в консоль/лог все данные `String args[]` и посмотреть что туда приходит. В вопросе в запуске указано слишком много пробелов, попробуйте удалить все лишние, оставьте только по одному пробелу, двойные пробелы и больше удалите, должно заработать. Поскольку Вашу версию java я не знаю, но помню была бага с методом split, которая возвращала пустую строку если первый символ пробел (она вызывается для args).